# git lost 4 hours of work to local files

Tags: git

Some files I spent about 4 hours editing reverted themselves to a previous state, I'd love to know how, and if possible to recover those changes.

Here is the sequence of events:

1. I have a project that involves two submodules.
2. I made changes to those modules (the originals), committed, pushed
3. I made changes to code in my project, outside of those submodules.
4. I ran  `git submodule update --remote`
5. It failed, because I had edited a file in one of the submodules
6. I ran `git stash save path/to/file` - which failed because I was in the root,
7. I ran `git stash save path/to/module/path/to/file` which worked
8. I ran `git submodule update --remote` again - which succeeded
9. My edited files reverted to their previous state

As I say, this is several hours of work, and about 4 files that have magically reverted, without warning.

Any thoughts on how I can avoid this in the future (aside from regularly committing my files, which I neglected to do in this case)

It failed

Answer (score 1):

I feel like a right idiot, the failed stash apparently saved all the local files, and while I had tried `git stash apply` the subsequent stashing had pushed it down a level, so I had to run `git stash apply @stash{1}`

Comment: For next time, you can try giving your stash a name via `git stash save "4 tedious hours of work"`.  Then when you want to apply it, use `git stash apply stash^{/tedious}`.

Comment: I'll remember that - though the stashing the work was actually a mistake, I was trying to stash a file in the submodule, apparently when you stash a file that doesn't exist (or exists, but isn't tracked perhaps) git stashes everything!

Comment: No.  Git is a _repository_-based VCS, meaning that when you stash, it will stash _all_ files which have been staged.  So you generally don't talk about stashing a single file in Git, this is incorrect thinking.

Comment: I think the problem was I stashed from within my root project, when I should have stashed from the submodule. Having said that - I hadn't intended to make a change to that file at all.